# Making Text To Columns Range Dynamic

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I would like to make the text to columns range dynamic in my macro.
But if i try to put the myRange in there it doesn't work.
I can't find any information around the web to make the text to columns dynamic.

The original (recorded code):

```
Sub Macro3()
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Selection, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), DecimalSeparator:=".", ThousandsSeparator:=",", _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End sub
```

After editing (but can't get it to work):

```
Sub Macro3()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Selection

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=myRange, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), DecimalSeparator:=".", ThousandsSeparator:=",", _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

I think there would be an easy solve, but i searched for it and can't find any solutions to figure it out.

Can anyone help with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify a delimiter, so even your first bit of code fails. I've set the comma option to true to get the code to run. You may want to use a different delimiter.

You can assign any range to MyRange, as long as it is suitable for the text to columns operation, i.e. one column only and data that suits the pattern you have set up, i.e. only two elements in each row. Then don't user `Selection.TextToColumns` but `myRange.TextToColumns`.

```
Sub Macro4()
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Range("A1:A20") ' you may need to qualify the range with sheet name, etc.

    myRange.TextToColumns Destination:=myRange, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), DecimalSeparator:=".", ThousandsSeparator:=",", _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Teylyn,

I finally figured out now.
I needed to change selection.textocolumns into myRange.TexttoColumns.

I didn't change the Comma, cause it was only for changing dataformatting from US to EU.

My final code is this:
    Sub Macro3()

```
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Selection

    myRange.TextToColumns Destination:=myRange, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), DecimalSeparator:=".", ThousandsSeparator:=",", _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```